# How to set an attribute to route definition in Slim4 and use it in a middleware

Tags: slim, slim-4

I need to set a custom attribute in the route definition and use it a route middleware. For example, I need to manage the refer page to redirect the user after the login.

This is my routes definition:

```
return function (App $app) {
    $app->get('/', Home::class. ':home')->setName('home');
    $app->get('/login', UserAction::class. ':getLogin')->setName('login')->setAttribute('norefer',true);
    $app->post('/login', UserAction::class. ':postLogin');
};
```

The `->setAttribute('norefer',true);` is what I'm looking for and seems it doesn't exist.

I need this attribute using `->getAttribute("norefer")` in a middleware so I can store the last referable page visited by the user:

```
public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
{
    $routeContext = RouteContext::fromRequest($request);
    $route = $routeContext->getRoute();
    if (!empty($route) && !$routeContext->getRoute()->getAttribute("norefer")) {
        $referName = $routeContext->getRoute()->getName();
        $referArgs = $routeContext->getRoute()->getArguments();
        $this->session->set("referName", $referName);
        $this->session->set("referArgs", $referArgs);
    }
    return $handler->handle($request);
}
```

So, in the session I can store the last referable page and use it after the login process to redirect the user to his page.

Comment: Maybe the answer simply the route arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `NoRefererMiddleware` to routes you want to exclude from the redirection logic. NoRefererMiddleware just sets a `noreferer` attribute to the request object if its called.

```php
<?php

use App\Middleware\NoRefererMiddleware;
use Slim\App;

return function (App $app) {
    $app->get('/', Home::class. ':home')->setName('home');
    $app->get('/login', UserAction::class. ':getLogin')->setName('login')->add(NoRefererMiddleware::class);
    $app->post('/login', UserAction::class. ':postLogin');
};
```

File: src/Middleware/NoRefererMiddleware.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

final class NoRefererMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        $request = $request->withAttribute('noreferer', true);

        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```php
public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
{
    $noReferer = $request->getAttribute('noreferer');

    if ($noReferer !== true) {
        $routeContext = RouteContext::fromRequest($request);
        $route = $routeContext->getRoute();
        if ($route !== null) {
            $referName = $routeContext->getRoute()->getName();
            $referArgs = $routeContext->getRoute()->getArguments();
            $this->session->set('referName', $referName);
            $this->session->set('referArgs', $referArgs);
        }
    }

    return $handler->handle($request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hoped there was withAttribute() directly in Route object. What do you think about setting a new argument instead of using a new middleware?

Comment: You're welcome. I think route arguments are not intended for this use case. Route arguments are for the "placeholders" of the path e.g. `'/books/{id}'`, but not for "internal" attributes like this.

Comment: PS: If have have a single route you want to exclude, why not check for the route name? Then you don't need the NoRefererMiddleware.

Comment: Unfortunately I have more than one, the login was just an example (another one logout, lostpassword, revive cookie route and so on..).
BTW I'm using your slim4 skeleton more than slim guide! Really thanks.